# write a power shell script to maintain latest 5 releases and deleting all other timestamp releases in a directory

Tags: powershell

```
$path = "D:\ProfileServiceQAT"

$Temp = "D:\\temp1"

$limit = (Get-Date).Adddays(-5)

$Folder = Get-ChildItem  $path | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 5


$Folder | Copy-Item -Destination $Temp

Remove-Item   $path\* -Recurse

Move-Item $Temp\* -Destination $path

Remove-Item $Temp\* -Recurse
```

In this above script whenever I run this script, I am only getting empty timestamp releases into temp and then into the path without contents. Please let me know where it going wrong

Comment: Add `-Recurse` to the `Copy-Item` command

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias R.Jessen.  Its working fine

Comment: Is there any way we can give the path from the pipeline instead of giving directly in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and mark it answer, if it helps you

```
$path = "D:\ProfileServiceQAT"

$Temp = "D:\temp1"

$limit = (Get-Date).Adddays(-5)

$Folder = Get-ChildItem  $path | Sort CreationTime -Descending|Where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $limit}

$Folder | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: The above code will simply removes the files and folders from the $path folder which are modified before 5 days

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to specify the `-Recurse` switch when you want to copy the whole directory structure with contents - otherwise it just creates the copy of the directory itself, nothing below it.

```
$Folder | Copy-Item -Destination $Temp -Recurse
```